# Error expected ';' before 'scanf'

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Estoy tratando de poder sacar el area de un triangulo mi profesor me paso el programa y a el si le corrió, en cambio a mi y a mis compañeros no nos sale, espero contar con su ayuda y muchas gracias

[Error] expected ';' before 'scanf'

Y mi programa es este

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float b,h,a;
    printf("\n Dame la base del triangulo: ");
    scanf("%f",&b);
    printf("\n Dame la altura del triangulo: ")
    scanf("%f",&h);
    a=(b*h)/2;
    printf("\n El área del triangulo es: ")
    printf("\n");
    system ("pause");
    return (0);
    
    
}
```

Comment: Tienes un typo en el segundo printf ya que omitiste el ; al final de dicha línea

Comment: a tienes razon perdon se me olvido ). muchas gracias

Comment: Y ahora que veo de nuevo es el mismo error en el último printf

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("\n Dame la altura del triangulo: ");
```

te falta un punto y coma en dos instrucciones y ya ;)

```
printf("\n El área del triangulo es: ");
```